# How to get filtered and sorted result set from Clarity Datagrid?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to get the filtered sorted data out of an angular clarity datagrid.

The @Output provided by the 'clr-datagrid' component 'clrDgRefresh' only provides the specifics around pagination, sorting and filtering.

I wanted to get the data out of the filtered table to show addresses on a google map and aggregate some specific metrics about the filtered table ie average, max, min etc.

Is here a way to do this? Or should I start on a PR to extend 'clr-datagrid' with an additional @Output?

Comment: We don't support this and I don't think its something that we would in the future. We had similar requests in the past for a csv or pdf type export functionality and one of the main issues here is that we allow any kind of HTML in the cells ... while this makes them more customizable, it makes it difficult to make them exportable. If you are using the standard string filters and sorting you could do the filtering/sorting on the app side to do the aggregation. We keep built-ins here to see what they are doing: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/clr-angular/data/datagrid/built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the datagrid in question as a ViewRef. And found an 'item' member on the class that has what I need.